# Understand cakePHP 3.3 nomenclature

Tags: php, function, arguments, cakephp-3.0

New to CakePHP 3.3. I looked across multiple sites (Stack Overflow, W3Schools, etc.) but cannot find an answer to:

What does this piece of code mean/do in a CakePHP tutorial:

public function initialize (array $config)

1) public: I understand this can either be public, private, or protected

2) function: Is this creating a function called "initialize()"?

3) initialize(): I understand this is a method built into CakePHP, but what does it do?

4) array $config: Are these two words combined or are they separate of each other? Why do I need both words, what is the influence of one on the other?

Background: This comes from the CakePHP tutorial and is found in multiple .php files. Not sure what is php code and what is unique CakePHP terminology.

Comment: I think you should start with a tutorial that explains the basics of PHP and THEN start with a framework, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think This is very good question...!!! This question is applied for all framework not bounded only for CakePHP.

```
function my_function(array $arr, int $int, $bool $active)
{
      /// function body
}
```

In technical it knows as **Type Hinting**

> Type declarations allow functions to require that parameters are of a
>   certain type at call time. If the given value is of the incorrect
>   type, then an error is generated: in PHP 5, this will be a recoverable
>   fatal error, while PHP 7 will throw a TypeError exception.
>
> To specify a type declaration, the type name should be added before
>   the parameter name. The declaration can be made to accept NULL values
>   if the default value of the parameter is set to NULL.

Check about valid types paramater

[image]

**Reference:** http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

I see at least one great advantage of using type hinting: readability. It's easier to see what kind of parameter a function/method expects.

Some will see this as a drawback that if you don't respect a type hint and pass some not-type-valid parameter, you'll get a catchable fatal error. However,

- I personally think it forces the developer to respect your interfaces more
- It allows your code to just work with the received parameters.
- The generated error is catchable.

**Question of Performance?**

- Making the decision of using type hints or not using type hints should not be the result of performances considerations. You should use or not use the feature.
- Even if there is some performance impact, it should be pretty minimal. I would say there are many parts of your code that you should optimize before considering this.

**Conclusion**

In conclusion, a personal opinion: I quite often use those type hints, just so:

- Other Developers using my code know what they are expected to pass in (they don't always read the documentation...)
- If they don't do what is expected, it fails; hard; in a way they immediately notice
- My code doesn't have to check if the received parameter is of the right type: I know it is, as PHP enforces that for me.